# Does jquery work with SVG nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

A simple question...does jQuery work with SVG nodes? I would like to change attributes on SVG nodes like I do with HTMLElement.

Olivier

Comment: I've had success combining jQuery 1.8 with RaphaelJS, which hints at a positive answer to your question. Having said that, I've yet to test my project fully cross-browser, so I wouldn't want to say for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : with jQuery 1.9.1 I am able to change attributes of SVG Elements.

Olivier